# How to check for incoming new messages using Gmail API

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I have set up a python script that can pull data from Gmail account, but I would like to set it up in a way that it would only pull new message since the last time I made the API call (I will be pinging the server regularly).

I have looked at Push notification and Pub/Sub, but I am not quite sure if these are relevant or I should be looking at something else. Gmail also has Users.history: list function, but I am wondering if this can be used in any useful way.

Comment: Gmail API Push Notifications is the approach you should take. Gmail will ping your server anytime new emails arrive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [list messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) as you usually do, but saying that you want messages after a certain timestamp. This way, you can poll for new messages e.g. every minute, giving the last time you checked for messages in `seconds since the epoch`:

**Request**

```
q = is:unread AND after:<time_since_epoch_in_seconds>

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?q=is%3Aunread+AND+after%3A1446461721&access_token={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "150c7d689ef7cdf7",
   "threadId": "150c7d689ef7cdf7"
  }
 ],
 "resultSizeEstimate": 1
}
```

Then you just save the timestamp when you issued the request, and use this timestamp one minute later.

Comment: Note that this will have race condition issues if there are other users/apps interacting with the inbox that can mark messages as read.

Comment: @user2857014 Sweet :) No problem!

Comment: I am using the seconds since the epoch and it's mostly working fine, except it does not recognize some of the newest messages. Is there any possible explanation for this? @Tholle or anyone else?

Comment: nevermind the question above. I was pulling from the wrong email address.