# Automatic partial forward of a mail

Tags: email, forward

I receive daily a message on my address at gmail.com and need to automatically forward ONLY a part of it.

In detail, the received mail contains a link. I would forward ONLY this link, without other informations regarding the original sender of this mail.

I searched the answer to my problem in several tutorials and online documentation, but unsuccessfully.

I think the solution can be a script, but I have no idea how to....

Comment: As it is, this is much too broad. At least a laundry list of scripting languages you can imagine using would reduce the scope of this to *almost* acceptable, but typically, we want to see a concrete attempt. Gmail has an API and you can access Gmail over IMAP; a preference for one or the other would also help guide the effort.

Comment: ... If only just to point you to an existing duplicate with a good answer.  Like e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467106/how-to-check-for-incoming-new-messages-using-gmail-api